# Comparison of data in Python

Tags: python, uml

I have UML diagram like this:

```
                   School
                      |
                   Teacher
                      |
                   Children
```

I am accessing the data in classes, `School`, `Teache`r and `Children` in python like this:

```
for Teacher in School.getTeachers():
        print Teacher.getName()
        for Children in Teacher.getChildrens():
            print Children.getName()
```

This is the output that I'm getting:

```
Mr. Smith
A
B
C
D
E
F
Mr. Paul
D
E
F
```

I want to compare every child name under `teacher1` with every child name under teacher two.

The output of this two should be:

> A,B,C are not under Mr. Paul

Comment: 1) what is the question? 2) what have you tried?

Comment: I want to compare every children name under teacher1 with every children name under teacher two. Like the output of this two should be A,B,C are not under Mr. Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Basic code

Use sets, something like this:

```
teachers = list(School.getTeachers())
teacher1 = teachers[0]
teacher2 = teachers[1]

diff = set(teacher1.getChildrens()) - set(teacher2.getChildrens())
print "%s are not under %s" % (", ".join(c.getName() for c in diff), teacher2.getName())
```

## Extended example

```
>>> class Student(object):
...     def __init__(self, name):
...         self.name = name
...     def getName(self):
...         return self.name    
... 
>>> class Teacher(object):
...     def __init__(self, name, students):
...         self.name = name
...         self.students = students
...     def getChildrens(self):
...         return self.students
...     def getName(self):
...         return self.name
... 
>>> class School(object):
...     def __init__(self, teachers):
...         self.teachers = teachers
...     def getTeachers(self):
...         return self.teachers
... 
>>> students = [Student("A"), Student("B"), Student("C"), Student("D"), Student("E"), Student("F"), ]
>>> s = Teacher("Smith", students)
>>> p = Teacher("Paul", students[3:])
>>> school = School([s, p])
>>> 
>>> teachers = list(school.getTeachers())
>>> teacher1 = teachers[0]
>>> teacher2 = teachers[1]
>>> 
>>> diff = set(teacher1.getChildrens()) - set(teacher2.getChildrens())
>>> print "%s are not under %s" % (", ".join(c.getName() for c in diff), teacher2.getName())
B, C, A are not under Paul
```

Comment: I am catching data from a file so I exactly don't know How many Teachers and Children I will get from a file :(

Comment: teacher1.getchildren doesn't work for the API I am using. I can use to loops as shown in my code to fetch the values

Comment: I don't know that either point matters. If you can get a teacher and you can get the teacher's children as some sort of iterable, then you can put the children into a set. You should be able to diff one teacher's students against the other's and generate the output I show.